# PPTP VPN client connectivity not working

Tags: vpn, pptp

I am trying to connect to my VPN from my `tonidoplug`. I followed the steps found in [PPTP Client](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-debian.phtml).

But I am getting the below error now:

```
$ sudo pon codeme debug dump logfd 2 nodetach
Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: No such device or address /usr/sbin/pppd: Please load the ppp_generic kernel module.
```

From what I found somewhere in the Internet I tried adding the line `alias char-major-108 ppp_generic` to my `/etc/modprobe.d/modules.conf` file and rebooted the device. Still am not able to connect to VPN.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at least part of the problem is that you don't have `pppd` installed.

Try installing `pppd`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pppd
```